# ¿Cómo puedo mandar en el request varios valores seleccionados en un checkbox laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Saludos una consulta tengo un checkbox con varias preguntas que lo obtengo de una tabla y lo genero con un **foreach** pero al momento de guardar este formulario lo único que me envía es la primera opción que seleccioné y no envía si selecciono más opciones.

Respuesta es el array que estoy almacenando los resultados de mi **foreach**, pero siempre solo guarda uno así seleccione los 3 o más checks que se generan.

Gracias por su  ayuda.

Aquí esta mi vista:

```
<td name = "pregunta[]">{{$pre->pregunta}}</td>
   <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="id[]" value="{{$pre->id}}">
   <input type="hidden" id="custname" name="pregunta[]" value="{{$pre->pregunta}}">
    @php
    $i =0;
    @endphp
    @foreach(explode(',', $pre->opciones) as $info)

      <td ><input type="checkbox"  name="respuesta[]" value="{{$i}}">{{$info}}</td>
       @php
       $i++;
       @endphp
    @endforeach
```

Y aquí esta de mi controlador:

```
for($conta = 0 ; $conta < count($request->id) ; $conta++  ){
            $id =$request->id[$conta];
            $pregunta =$request->pregunta[$conta];
            $respuesta = $request->respuesta[$conta];

            var_dump($id);
            var_dump($pregunta);
            var_dump($respuesta);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `$request->id`?

Comment: $request id es el id de la pregunta,  el problema esta en el respuesta ya que ese me esta retornando ya un array con varias respuestas pero dentro de esas repuestas esta mi la repuesta del checkbox que de las tres opciones solo me retorna una, y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta lo que devuelve `var_dump($request->respuesta);`?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tendrías que hacer es que respuestas sea un array multidimensional como: $respuestas[{{$pre->id }}][] donde la primera dimensión seria tu id de la pregunta y la segunda dimensión va a ser un array de las respuestas del checkbox.
Te pongo el código:

```
        <td name = "pregunta[]">Pregunta</td>
            <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="id[{{$pre->id}}]" value="{{$pre->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" id="custname" name="pregunta[{{$pre->id}}]" value="{{$pre->pregunta}}">
            @php
                $i =0;
                @foreach(explode(',', $opciones) as $info)
            @endphp
                <td><input type="checkbox"  name="respuesta[{{$pre->id}}][]" value="{{ $i }}">{{ $info }}</td>
            @php    
                    $i++;
            @endphp
        @endforeach
```

Dando por resultado en el var_dump

```
array(3) { 
    ["id"]=> array(2) { [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "2" } 
    ["pregunta"]=> array(2) { [1]=> string(10) "Pregunta 1" [2]=> string(10) "Pregunta 2" } 
    ["respuesta"]=> array(2) { 
         [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "uno" [1]=> string(4) " dos" } 
         [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) " cinco" [1]=> string(5) " seis" } 
    } 
}
```

Da los valores "uno", "dos", etc. porque hice pruebas con palabras y no con indices como lo expusiste.

En este caso, te recomiendo en el controlador hacer un foreach en lugar de un for, ya que en mi caso el array empieza en el indice 1 y no en el 0, tronaría el ciclo mostrando un error offset.